# com.google.android.gcm.server where art thou

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Working on a first try of GCM.  On the server side I create the standard project and managed to upload it to google app engine.

Trying to add GCM to Eclipse "WebApplication Project" I cannot seem to resolve:  com.google.android.gcm.server.

I have copied the gcm-server.jar to this directory: `war/WEB-INF/lib/gcm-server.jar`.

Any help?

Comment: have you configured `Java Build Path` in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.

go to the properties of your projects -> google -> webapplication and add your jar there.

hope it works for u.